# How to declare variable without returning it in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to send a function to a parent component through an event, but when i try to declare the variable that will store the function inside 'data(){return: }' the function gets executed as soon as the variable receives it. I need to find a place to declare the variable without executing the function inside it automatically.

```
//child
export default: {
    data() {
        return {
            submit_method: { type: Function }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        open(type) {
            if(type == 'newFolder') {
                this.$refs.newFolder.show()
                this.submit_method = this.exportFile()
            } else {
                this.$refs.olderOmbudsman.show()
            }
        },
        exportFile() {
            if ( this.doc.origin.id != null ) {
                window.open(`${window.globals.API_SERVER}/ombudsman/doc/?page=${this.doc.page}&origin=${this.doc.origin.id}`, '_target')
            }else{
                alert("Choose the origin!");
            }
        }
    },
    activated() {
        this.$emit('export-ombudsman', submit_method)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you want to pass a function to the parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first oddity I notice is this:

```js
return {
    submit_method: { type: Function }
}
```

Props support types, `data` does not. All you're doing here is assigning the object `{type: Function}` to `submit_method`.

Then there's this:

```js
this.submit_method = this.exportFile()
```

This is invoking the method immediately. I assume you meant this:

```js
this.submit_method = this.exportFile
```

Then we've got this:

```js
this.$emit('export-ombudsman', submit_method)
```

In templates you need to drop the `this.` for accessing members but you can't do it in your JavaScript. This needs to be:

```js
this.$emit('export-ombudsman', this.submit_method)
```

All of which assumes that `submit_method` is dynamic. If it isn't then you can just pass `exportFile` directly:

```js
this.$emit('export-ombudsman', this.exportFile)
```

Even if you do need the function to be dynamic there isn't any need for `submit_method` to be declared in your `data` unless you need it to be reactive. You can still save it to `this` even if it isn't in `data`.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know putting '()' after the method invoked it immediatly, that's what was happening. Also i do need the function to be reactive but i didnt know data doesnt take types. Should i just declare it as an empty property then?

Comment: @BrunoSouza Difficult for me to say what the initial value of `submit_method` should be without knowing how it will be used but `submit_method: null` would be sufficient if there isn't a more suitable value.